# Ask about phrase "Planet Earth" without "the"

Tags: grammar

I believe that the Earth is unique, so we need an article "the" before "Planet Earth", i.e. "the planet earth".

But I found that it is popular to use "Planet Earth" without "the". I don't know why .

Comment: In general you don't use an article ahead of a proper name.

Comment: @Hot Licks: The Vatican, the Louvre, the Sorbonne, the Hague, the Donald.

Comment: @Ricky - I said "in general" -- there are exceptions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word "Earth" is a name, just like "Mars." It does not require an article.

**Mars was nice, but now that we're back on Earth, how do you like it?**

Now the planet Earth, just like the planet Mars, is a planet that has a name.

**The planet Mars is further from the Sun than the planet Earth.**

On the other hand, Planet Earth (both words capitalized) is a place, and, just like Buckingham Palace, it does not require an article.

**Did you like Planet Earth? Wait till you see Planet Mars!**

Comment: The earth is 4.5 billion years old.  The earth's atmosphere consists of nitrogen and oxygen.  We need to save the earth.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Yeah. I keep wondering about that too, intermittently.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Apropos, you can't say "We need to save the mars."

Comment: @michael_timofeev: (as an afterthought) But we could, if we were so inclined, elect the Donald.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I don't need no bleedin' stripes. I come here to show off, make fun of people, and gain some knowledge in the process. Not necessarily in that order. Sometimes I'm just curious, though. Sloth is one of the seven cardinal sins, Timofeev-san.

Comment: *On the other hand, Planet Earth (both words capitalized) is a place, and, just like Buckingham Palace, it does not require an article.*  What about The Hague??  *The Hague is a city on the North Sea coast of the western Netherlands.*

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah. Let's not forget la France and l'Amerique.